# How to use dynamically created button for saving information to the database

Tags: android, sql, dynamic-data

I have to create button dynamically and use that button to save certain information to the database. I want to know that how can i do this.Plz explain with example.

Comment: What's your question. Creating a button dynamically or saving to a database?

Comment: Thanks for the replay Enrique and my question is how do i create button dynamically and how can i use the listener of dynamic button so that i can use it for saving information to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Simply. You can use this to create the `Button` dynamically.

```
LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*here is your code to save your info into database*/
    }
});
btn.setText("Save");
line.addView(btn);
```

Next, if you want to use `SqLite` you can create own class DBAdapter. Use this link to understand this 
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954

or this

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx.

There are so much information about this in Google.